# How to custom output file naming in Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

In Nuxt 2, I used the following configuration to control the naming of output files:

```
filenames: {
  app: () => '[name].js',
  chunk: () => '[name].js',
  css: () => '[name].css',
  img: () => '[path][name].[ext]',
  font: () => '[path][name].[ext]',
  video: () => '[path][name].[ext]'
}
```

(Source: [Nuxt 2 Documentation](https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build/#filenames))

However, in Nuxt 3, I would like to achieve a similar configuration to control the naming of output files without including hash values. Could you please guide me on what settings to use in Nuxt 3 to achieve this?

Thank you all for your assistance!

Answer (score -1):

In Nuxt 3, as it’s built on top of Vite/Rollup for the frontend part, you may need to rely on Vite’s configuration options to control how assets are named.

Please note that not adding a hash to filenames can affect long-term caching and might cause caching issues when you deploy updates since the browser may retain the old files. It’s generally recommended to include a hash in the filenames during production builds for cache busting. If you have a specific reason for not including hashes, then the configuration above should be a good starting point. However, ensure that you have other methods in place for cache busting when deploying new versions of your files.

```js
// nuxt.config.ts

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  nitro: {
    preset: 'server',
    output: {
      serverDir: 'output/server',
      publicDir: 'output/public',
    },
  },
  build: {
    // Rollup options to control output file names
    rollupConfig: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: '[name].js',
        chunkFileNames: '[name].js',
        assetFileNames: ({ name }) => {
          // Define naming convention based on the file type
          if (/\.css$/i.test(name)) {
            return '[name].css';
          }
          if (/\.(pngjpe?ggifsvgwebp)$/i.test(name)) {
            return 'img/[name][extname]';
          }
          if (/\.(woffwoff2eotttfotf)$/i.test(name)) {
            return 'fonts/[name][extname]';
          }
          if (/\.(mp4webmogv)$/i.test(name)) {
            return 'videos/[name][extname]';
          }
          // Fallback for other assets
          return '[name][extname]';
        },
      },
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it doesn't seem to be working. It appears that the hash is live in file name.

You can check my repository at this link:
GitHub Repository : https://github.com/Michael0520/nuxt3-test-deploy/blob/main/nuxt.config.ts

Comment: I guess the problem may be that the new version of the official document has removed this attribute, so this effect cannot be successfully completed.

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/nuxt-config#build-1